# What is the reference unit of the kgf reading on the Park spoke tension chart?

Tags: spokes, tension, torque

What is the reference unit  of the `kgf` reading on the Park spoke tension chart?  Is it `kgf/cm`?

[image: torque wrench spoke tension gauge for small wheels]

Comment: Isn’t it kilograms force, i.e. a force? 1kgf = 9.81N. kgf/cm (force over area) would be tension.

Answer (score 7):

Kilograms force. It is tension equal to a weight of that many kilograms pulling on the spoke under earth gravity.

Comment: I'm looking at various online conversion tools which take that value and convert it to Nm, and they want to know if it is `kgf/mm` or `kgf/cm` or `kgf/m` .

Comment: I think the deflection (mm) would depend on what material the spokes are made of. Each material has its own stress/strain curve.

Comment: @DennisWurster You are correct. Tensiometers all have charts that cross reference their deflection reading to each type of spoke for this reason.

Comment: @Tim Nm is a measure of torque.  kgf is a measure of force.  kfg/m is a measure of something else, but would be in the same units as N/m (which is very different to Nm).  Why are you trying to convert to Nm?

Comment: @throx: The Park spoke tension gauge uses a spring to pivot a piece of metal with a contact bolt on it, pushing that bolt up against the spoke, which resists the spring.   Imagine, instead of that spring, a torque wrench was being used to push some pivoting device up against the spoke. I am trying to find out the torque equivalents.  If the Park gauge reads 25 on a given spoke, where should the torque wrench be set to click to achieve the same amount of force against the spoke, and no more than that. Torque creates rotational *force*, right?

Comment: @Tim You can convert kg-f to N, which is another unit of force. For bike purposes you would have a hard time finding a situation where the rounding error of just multiplying by ten matters. I'm not totally clear on the question you're asking, but let me introduce another idea to you: You can create a new tensiometer chart by hanging a sequence of known weights off a spoke and seeing what the tool reads at each step, then drawing the curve. I'm pretty sure that's how extant charts are made, rather than doing fancy spring math.

Comment: It is true you could fashion a tensiometer that uses a torque wrench to apply measured force to a spoke, rather than using a spring of known force to do the same. But what numbers you would be applying on the torque wrench would depend completely on the geometry of the tool you made, ie the distance from the torque wrench pivot to the contact point.. I don't know if this is the same mental sandbox you're in.

Comment: (N is a unit of force, Nm is a unit of torque equal to one Newton pushing on a lever one meter long.)

Comment: @NathanKnutson : Trying to come up with a way to measure spoke tension on small wheels (recumbents and folders) since standard tension meters don't fit them except in a radial spoke pattern.  Doesn't the size of the wrench simply determine the "sweet spot" of the torque *range* and the degree to which the torque can be *finessed* by a human arm and hand? It's possible to tighten stem bolts with a two-foot long torque wrench, but difficult to finesse minor gradations in torque with the large tool. The effort changes as the size changes but the torque produced is an absolute.

Comment: Yeah it can be a tough one. I have built some fancy production BMX race 20" wheels with a Wheel Fanatyk and it worked, but they were straight gauge, not sure how well it would do on butted unless the transition was very near the threads.

Comment: I see what you're getting at though and can imagine something based on a torque wrench that is small enough to get in there, and it also would build the precision force-measuring part of the tool into something you already have, so that's an interesting idea.

Comment: @Tim The size of the tool you're making is what converts torque to lateral force on the spoke, not the size of the torque wrench.  It's the distance between the two points that are contacting the spoke in question.  Converting that to a tension could (probably) be done by testing a spoke in a radial pattern and calibrating it against a Park Tool's calibration table?  It's not going to be a linear correlation, I'd guess, but once you've done it for a particular type of spoke it should hold up.  I think.

Comment: The device might be able to use a modified camber bolt.  Something roughly egg-shaped, like a cam, that would pivot when the torque wrench turned it. Maximum spoke-deflection would occur when the long axis of the egg was perpendicular to the spoke.

Comment: @throx: Is the length of the spoke between the two pressure prongs the critical value?

Comment: @Tim No, tensiometers differ in that distance. Compare the park, dt, and wheel fanatyk. All over the place. What we're trying to tell you is the reading of the torque wrench is essentially multiplied by the distance to the contact point with the spoke. For example, look at a crows foot torque wrench adapter, which usually come with such a multiplier stamped on. You could do what you're talking about, but it would need to be based on the distance between the head of the wrench and the spoke contact point. It would need some clever design to make it not too fiddly, but sounds possible.

Comment: Also the rolling egg you've drawn would introduce bearing and contact friction into the torque reading

Comment: I need to find only the *functionally equivalent* reading on my device compared to a Park. Measure tension of a given 2mm standard spoke on a large wheel where a Park fits. "25". Repeat with my device. Repeat those same two steps at different tensions and for each kind of spoke I will be working with. I now know that when my device reads "x" on a given spoke it is the equivalent to a "y" reading from a Park. The original question remains, though, how sensitive a torque wrench is needed. My most sensitive beam style torque wrench (0 to 200 inch-lbs) has a tick-mark every 10 inch-lbs.

Comment: If you have something rolling along it like in the picture, the surface friction from the finish etc will impact the torque measurement, same as how a lubricated vs unlubricated thread shows very different torque for the same amount of thread preload

Comment: @NathanKnutson :  The reading doesn't have to be *correct*. It simply has to be *consistent*.  The device could have an 800-pound gorilla standing on tip-toe on the pivot and it still wouldn't matter.  Its reading is simply an index into the Park chart. I just have to translate the gorilla reading into the Park equivalent.  And we know the equivalent *experimentally*.

Answer (score 1):

1 kilogram or kilogram-force (kg or kgf) = 9.80665 newtons (N) = 35.2739619 ounces (oz) = 1000 grams (g) = 1000000 milligrams (mg) = 2.20462262 pounds (lbs) = 0.157473044 stones (st).